# Complex integration approach

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

How does one approach to solving integrals like:
$ \oint_C f(z)e^{1/z}dz$  where $C: |z| = 1$

Let's say f(z) is a complex function and it is defined inside $|z| = 1$, so the only problem is $z = 0$. Is there some way like the Cauchy integral formula? The function in my case is quite a pain and I cannot figure out how to solve it.

Comment: The given integral is the conjugate of the integral over C of $g(z)e^{z} z^{-2}$ where g is the conjugate of f. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that $f$ is analytic inside $C$ such that

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n z^n$$

$\forall |z| \lt 1$.  Then expanding the exponential in its Laurent series about the essential singularity at $z=0$, we have the integral being

$$\oint_C dz \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n z^n \, \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac1{m! z^m} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac1{m!} \oint_C dz \, z^{n-m}$$

We can exchange the order of summation and integration because the series converge.  Now we see that, by Cauchy's theorem, the integral is equal to zero except when $m=n+1$, when it equals $i 2 \pi$.  Thus, the integral is equal to

$$\oint_C dz \, f(z) e^{1/z} = i 2 \pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f_n}{(n+1)!} $$

and without further information about $f$, that's as far as one can take this.